# How can I turn off Letterbox on iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone-5

The size looks the same as iPhone 4 and there are two black bar on top and below the app. Is the area the actual preview or is the area INSIDE the black bar the actual preview?

[image]

and below the tableview

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn no one wants to answer.....Look like if I just add the splash screen for Retina 4 inch, it will turn off the Letterbox.